# Auto layout + scaled views

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, constraints

Up until iOS 8, Auto Layout used the transformed dimensions of a scaled view, and factored in that scale when laying out. So, say you have a 0.5x transform on a view, and set that view to use the same dimensions as another, unscaled view - Auto Layout keeps those views the same size. Good-o:

[image: iOS 7 behaviour]

Since iOS 8 though, Auto Layout now seems to be ignoring transformed dimensions, which means that it's performing layout on the un-transformed coordinate system and making stuff look weird - now, with scaled-down views, I've got masses of whitespace:

[image: iOS 8 behaviour]

So; I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about how to get that original behaviour back? I'd like to override alignmentRectForFrame: and frameForAlignmentRect: and provide transformed values there, but they're never called.

Anyone got anything else?

Cheers!

(For reference, [here's the little Xcode project demonstrating the issue](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6956432/AutoLayoutScaleTest.zip))